# grails 2.0 including resources the simple way?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I've been battling various resource inclusion issues in my migration from Grails 1.3.7 from Grails 2.0, probably not understanding a few things to begin with.

Firstly, what does

```
<g:javascript library="application" />
```

do? (this was in the default main.gsp provided in Grails 1.3.7).

Secondly, for including jquery across my application, can I just do

```
<r:require module='jquery' />
<r:layoutResources />
```

in the top of my main sitemesh page that does the

```
 <g:layoutHead /> 
    ...
 <g:layoutBody />
```

and "be done with it", using the

```
<r:layoutResources />
```

a second time after the

```
 <g:layoutBody />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes I struggled a little with this at first too.

So firstly the `<g:javascript library="application" />` refers to a module defined in a config/*.Resources.groovy file (default is config/ApplicationResources.groovy), inside that you have named modules, eg:

```
modules = {
    application {
          resource url: 'js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js', disposition: 'head'
  }
}
```

Secondly by example a Grails2 main.gsp (cutdown a lot here):

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/redmond', file: 'jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css')}" type="text/css">

    <g:layoutHead/>
    <g:javascript library="jquery"/>

    <r:require module="application"/>
    <r:layoutResources/>

</head>

<body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <r:layoutResources/>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that sets you in the right direction

Comment: Question - is the "application" in the g:javascript tag, as well as the one in the r:require tag, referring to the "Application" prefix of ApplicationResources.groovy, or referring to the application {} declaration inside ApplicationResources.groovy?

Comment: I'm thinking it is just the one in ApplicationResouces.groovy, where any file you put in this config directory will be picked up, from the semi-confusing documentation on this subject, and as far as I can tell no previous documentation on the original question (in 1.3.7).

Comment: It refers to the name of the module in the file.  The file name  pattern is *Resource.groovy; so it could have been MyResources.groovy and the module name could have been "app"  but then the r:require would have had to been updated to point to "app"....I am quite sure that g:javascript is the same